# WordPress Visual Composer set random class

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to set a random class to a div element created via Visual Composer without success.

My Jquery code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var classes = ['1','2', '3']; 
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);
  jQuery('.page-id-99 .vc_grid-item').addClass(classes[random ]);
});
```

Will not work.
But setting up the same to the .page-id-99 will work as

```
 jQuery('.page-id-99').addClass(classes[random ]);
```

It seems that I cannot target anything after or inside the DIV vc_grid-container

Anything other elements before or after can be amended. (my classes are correct)

Anybody knows why and if there is a solution?

Comment: **Will not work** - Can you explain?

Comment: What is the generated HTML?

Comment: Does it work if your class names don't begin with a number?  I think those are invalid class names

Comment: Nothing is accessible under the container with the class .vc_grid-container, I can add to vc_grid-container but any div/elements under this is not working.